# How to recursively check files with Prettier

Tags: prettier

I tried using:

```
prettier --config .prettierrc.json --check .
```

and my config is like so:

```
{
  "semi": true
}
```

and it didn't check subdirectories. How can I tell prettier to do things recursively?

This seems to work:

```
prettier --config .prettierrc.json --check '**/**'
```

and so does this:

```
prettier --config .prettierrc.json --check '**'
```

but those seem like pretty non-standard commands. What is the canonical way to search recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `glob patterns` with **prettier**,
to search recursively you can use `**` aka globstar

[referencing the **Glob** documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md)

`**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

[referencing the **prettier** **command line interface** documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html)

```sh
prettier --single-quote --trailing-comma es5 --write "{app,__{tests,mocks}__}/**/*.js"
```

Don't forget the quotes around the globs! The quotes make sure that Prettier expands the globs rather than your shell, for cross-platform usage. The [glob syntax from the glob module](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md#glob-primer) is used.

Prettier CLI will ignore files located in `node_modules` directory. To opt-out from this behavior use `--with-node-modules` flag.